# how to listen event from form in dynamic number of forms php

Tags: php, forms

I have some PHP code that generates and edits forms of users. The number of forms depend on number of users registered. As a developer, I don't know what's the number of users that can register per day.

The code is like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) 
{
    echo "<form method='post'> 
    <input type='text' name='fname'>
    <input type='text' name='lname'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='save'></form>";
}
```

This code can repeat with 4 or 5 or ++ users. When i do:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 //code
}
```

for recovering the value of the two inputs.

How does the PHP know the source of the event? It can make a mistake because all button has the same name? Please help me!

Comment: What code are you doing where it says `//code`? I guess I'm a bit confused as to why you have to be concerned about which form they are submitting since the form doesn't appear to have any specific identifier (like a primary key or something).

Comment: //code it says any code to recover and user the two inputs

Answer (score 1):

You can give the button different names then:

```
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) 
{
  echo "<form method='post'> 
  <input type='text' name='fname'>
  <input type='text' name='lname'>
  <input type='submit' name='submit".$i."' value='save'></form>";
}
```

And then loop through the names to see if (and which) button is pressed:

```
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) 
{    
  if(isset($_POST['submit'.$i]))
  {
   //code
  }
}
```

If in addition you want to distinguish post values of the inputfields you could index their names alike.